# jquery returning json data as undefined and images are not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to gain access within the last array of the json file and return the value from the "data" array of the json file and put it into the choiceSelection array. However, on my local host, it returns an undefined value and the images would not load. Can anyone help me out? I apologise if I haven't clearly explained my problem/logic and so please ask me for more details, if you're not sure. Thanks!

javascript code

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {


            if(json[2].data){
            for (i = 0; i < json[3].data.length; i++) {
                choiceSelection[i] = new Array;
                choiceSelection[i][0] = json[2].data[i].question;
                choiceSelection[i][1] = json[2].data[i].correctChoice;
                choiceSelection[i][2] = json[2].data[i].choice1;
                choiceSelection[i][3] = json[2].data[i].choice2;
            }
            // choiceSelection.length = choiceSelection.length;
            displayQuestion();
            console.log(json[2]);
          }



        })
```

json file

```
[
  {
    "name": "match numbers 1",
    "template": "matching",
    "data": [
      [
        "six",
        "Images/Number6.jpg"
      ],
      [
        "eight",
        "Images/Number8.jpg"
      ],
      [
        "nine",
        "Images/Number9.jpg"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "order numbers 1",
    "template": "ordering",
    "data": [
      [
        "Images/Number6.jpg"
      ],
      [
        "Images/Number8.jpg"
      ],
      [
        "Images/Number9.jpg"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "animal",
    "template": "picture game",
    "data": [
      {
        "question": "Where is the cat?",
        "correctChoice": "Images/5cats.jpg",
        "choice1": "Images/squirrel.png",
        "choice2": "Images/beagle.png"
      },
      {
        "question": "Where is the cat?",
        "correctChoice": "Images/5cats.jpg",
        "choice1": "Images/squirrel.png",
        "choice2": "Images/beagle.png"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Edit 1: change json[i] to json[2].data. Still undefined
Edit 2: changed json[2].data. to json[2].data[i] and used json[3].data.length in the for statement. It works perfectly now. Thank you everyone for the help!:)

Comment: Could you post your project structure?

Comment: You're accessing `json[i]` which only has `name`, `template`, and `data` properties. If you want to access the `data` property of the last element in `json`, use `json[2].data` instead of `json` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Need consistent structure in each item in main array. You have 3 items and structure of `data` in each is different

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have tried, but again undefined

Comment: Change your `for` to loop over `json[2].data`

Comment: I'm surprised you want to map each object to an array like that. Being able to write `choiceSelection[i].question` is much more meaningful than `choiceSelection[i][0]`.

Comment: If your attempt is what you've changed in the main question, you missed the `json.length` in the `for` statement.

Comment: @charlietfl is that the reason why it it is returning as undefined?

Comment: That's part of it. Then each object would be `json[2].data[i]` and properties would be like `json[2].data[i].question` but can simplify a bit by storing reference to object `var obj= json[2].data[i]; console.log(obj.question)`

Comment: I highly suggest using the debugger in the developer tools of a browser; set a breakpoint in your loop and see what the values of these objects are. Or use `console.log(json[2].data)`. Basically, start using the tools to see what your code is doing and adjust it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the hassle out of your code and use some ES6 destructuring to get at your data more easily.

```js
const json = '[{"name":"match numbers 1","template":"matching","data":[["six","Images/Number6.jpg"],["eight","Images/Number8.jpg"],["nine","Images/Number9.jpg"]]},{"name":"order numbers 1","template":"ordering","data":[["Images/Number6.jpg"],["Images/Number8.jpg"],["Images/Number9.jpg"]]},{"name":"animal","template":"picture game","data":[{"question":"Where is the cat?","correctChoice":"Images/5cats.jpg","choice1":"Images/squirrel.png","choice2":"Images/beagle.png"},{"question":"Where is the cat?","correctChoice":"Images/5cats.jpg","choice1":"Images/squirrel.png","choice2":"Images/beagle.png"}]}]'

function getJSON(endpoint, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(JSON.parse(json)), 1000);
}

// grab the third object from the response data
getJSON('data.json', function([ ,,obj ]) {

  // grab the data array from that object but relabel it
  // `choiceSelection
  const { data: choiceSelection } = obj;

  // then use the object property keys to get access
  // to the data instead of indexes. Much easier.
  console.log(choiceSelection[0].question);
  console.log(choiceSelection[1].question);
});
```

Comment: except now Op needs to transpile es6 code. Highly unlikely they are familiar with doing that.

Comment: Not in modern browsers. I tested this without the need to transpile the code.

Comment: right but browsers like IE 11 and older mobile browsers don't support it,